# Does GROUP negate using ORDER BY in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a Pig script where I'm trying to order certain user events by datetime (UNIX timestamps) and then group the events by userid. The script doesn't generate any errors, and it does group the event by userid, but the events are not ending up sorted by datetime. This leads me to wonder if doing a group after an order by operation might undo the sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order is only guaranteed [immediately following](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#order-by) the use of `ORDER BY`. Further processing may destroy the order.

Alternatively, you can perform the grouping and then use `ORDER BY` in a nested foreach to order each bag of records separately.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the nested foreach exactly as you suggested and it worked.